# Error in NumPy: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I was working on a cournot problem, but was getting this error:

> `TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`

Can anyone help me locate the error I am getting?

Comment: Could you post the entire error traceback?

Comment: '---> 16 c1= broyden1(resid(c,p_node,alpha,eta,phi), c)
     17 phi1= np.polynomial.chebyshev.chebval(p_node,c1)
     18 q1= phi1*c1

\scipy\optimize\nonlin.py in nonlin_solve(F, x0, jacobian,..)
    274 
    275     dx = np.inf
--> 276     Fx = func(x)
    277     Fx_norm = norm(Fx)
    

C:\Users\Gagan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\nonlin.py in <lambda>(z)
    270 
    271     x0 = _as_inexact(x0)
--> 272     func = lambda z: _as_inexact(F(_array_like(z, x0))).flatten()
    273     x = x0.flatten()
    274 

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable'

Comment: @ElinaGilbert formating tip: 4 spaces for code, 8 spaces for indented code.

Comment: What arguments does `broyden1` take?  Function?  Initial value, args tuple?

Comment: @hpaulj  'broyden1' takes function and an initial guess value and returns the root finding solution. Here my initial guess is c=chebfit...

Comment: DOes it have a way of providing other arguments.  Most scipy `optimize` methods take an `args` parameter.  Another thing that you can do is wrap your `resid` in a function that only takes one parameter, and sets the others from globals.  ie. `lambda c: resid(c, ...)`.

Comment: @hpaulj its a part of my project where i have to use broyden method to solve the problem. Can you please help me revise the code correctly

Comment: I don't have your `broyden1` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `resid` returns an numpy-array at call-time.

Your need to give broyden a function, but gave it a called function, so it's not a function anymore, but was already evaluated to some array. This results in broyden1 to call the resulting numpy-array.

This is not equal:

```
c1= broyden1(resid(c,p_node,alpha,eta,phi), c)
c1= broyden1(resid, c)
```

I'm ignoring possible consequences here.

Comment: can you please suggest an alternative code to solve the same problem. Actually my motive is to find a coefficient c which makes mr-mc=0. Also, I have already tried    c1= broyden1(resid, c) but it gives non convergent solution with error